# Running Fragment Method from runnable in another thread in the mainactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to call a method to update a fragment. The method is called in the MainActivity class, in a separate thread, in a runable through a handler.

What I would normally do, in case I just want to call it from the MainActivity:

> (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findById(R.id.container).myMethod(args)

However, this doesn't seem to work. My method in the MainActivity:

> void methodInMainActivity() {
>
> ```
>     final Handler handler = new Handler();
>     workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
>                handler.post(new Runnable() {
>                    public void run() {
>                        ((ReceiveFragment)getFragmentManager().
>                                               findFragmentById(...)).myMethod();
>                    }
>                 });
>             }
>         }
>     });
>     workerThread.start();
> }
> ```

But the method is never run. Any clues?

Comment: i dont get that while loop, just go with while true since the thread wont run if its stopped anyway.

Comment: I stripped my method, but I forgot that one. It has a purpose, but just disregard it for now

Comment: have you ensured that the workerThread actually runs? if it does id try exchanging hat handler for activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable);